# Two limericks in one!

Tags: riddle, limerick

Two Limericks! Try and solve both :D

Limerick 1:

> His rage is beyond comprehension,
>   Changing forms in the rising of tension
>   His purple shorts seem
>   To always stay clean
>   And give his butt some suspension.

Limerick 2:

> I'm amazing 'cause I've got the force
>   To hold down a cow or a horse
>   As you've doubtlessly found,
>   I am always around,
>   And I'm constantly working, of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Limerick 1:

> The Incredible Hulk 
>  He has rage issues, he becomes the Hulk when he gets angry, and he has sweet purple shorts.

Limerick 2:

> Gravity. 
>  Its a force, it holds you (and livestock) down, and it never stops working.